# how to create a popup alert and take input in vscode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, coding-style, vscode-extensions

[image]
I want these type of popup in vscode extension.
But , I am not able to create it please help me on these.

I am trying in vscode but menubar is opened in debug page not seprate pop up

you can check example here
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Comment: search the API page for `quick`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode extension how to display a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705126/vscode-extension-how-to-display-a-form)